# Constructing projective geometries

Tags: projective-geometry, projective-space, combinatorial-designs

I'm currently reading through Hughes and Piper's textbook *Design Theory* and am stuck on a section on projective geometries (Chapter 1, pages 17-19).

The authors begin with the following definitions and construction.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

A few pages on, they present the following exercise:

[image]

It is in attempting this final exercise - in particular showing that  $\mathscr{P}_{2,2}(K)$ is not a projective plane - I've come to suspect I've not properly understood the above construction. My understanding is that in the construction of $\mathscr{P}_{n,i}(K)$, the points are the 1-dimensional subspaces of $V$ and the lines are the 2-dimensional subspaces of $V$. However, if this is the case, then whether a given $\mathscr{P}_{n,i}(K)$ is a projective plane shouldn't depend on $i$, the $g$-dimension of the blocks of $\mathscr{P}_{n,i}(K)$. But this can't be the case if Exercise 1.28 makes sense, as its truth implies $\mathscr{P}_{2,1}(K)$ is a projective plane while $\mathscr{P}_{2,2}(K)$ is not.

As an alternative, I tried assuming that the blocks of $\mathscr{P}_{n,i}(K)$ are themselves the "lines", but this leads to some of the $\mathscr{P}_{n,i}(K)$'s not even being projective geometries, which appears not to make sense, given that projective geometries are the objects supposedly being constructed.

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exercise 1.28 is indeed asking you to consider the blocks of $\mathscr{P}_{n,i}$ to be the "lines" of a geometry, and show that this incidence structure does not make a projective plane.

In the definitions given, a projective geometry only has points and lines; and $\mathscr{P}_{n,i}$ only has points and blocks (with blocks being the $i$-spaces of $\mathscr{P}(n, K)$). So this is the only interpretation that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.